# Internationalization and pay.nl does not seem to work properly together, any idea how to fix that one?

Tags: 6, ubercart, redirection, i18n-l10n

I am working on a website with four languages.

We use `Ubercart` with external payment facilities. We have `Paypal` and the following specific to Netherlands: `eBanking`, `iDEAL`, `MisterCash`. That works fine.

Now we are trying to get `pay.nl` to work. This one offers more methods of payments.

The request uses `/nl/` as expected with a path that looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/nl/order/paynl/notify/?...snip...
```

But the i18n module seems to change that to `/en/` instead:

```
http://www.example.com/en/order/paynl/notify/?...snip...
```

And that prevents the payment from being accepted.

Any idea what could be happening? Would there be a way to prevent translations from happening when hitting `/order`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be because of the "Language negotiation" configuration.

So check this configuration, which in D6 you can find via `/admin/settings/language/configure/language`. Experiment with the 4 available options in the Language negotiation selection list, to see if any of these options solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current settings are working really well with the site. If that's the only solution, it won't work for us...